# Populate dropdown from an entity using Spring-mvc and thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm working on an application in which I want to add a student to a meal using a dropdown in a form. My code looks as follows:

#### Meal.java

```
@Entity
public class Meal {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  private Student mealCook;

  private String mealName;

  private int mealPrice;
```

#### Student.java

```
@Entity
 public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String studentName;
```

#### MealController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/m")
public class MealController {

private final MealRepository mealRepository;
private final StudentRepository studentRepository;

public MealController(MealRepository mealRepository, StudentRepository studentRepository){
    this.mealRepository = mealRepository;
    this.studentRepository = studentRepository;
}

@GetMapping
public ModelAndView list(){
    Iterable<Meal> meals = this.mealRepository.findAll();
    return new ModelAndView("meals/list" , "meals", meals);
}

@GetMapping("{id}")
public ModelAndView view(@PathVariable("id") Meal meal) {
    return new ModelAndView("meals/view", "meal", meal);
}

@GetMapping(params = "form")
public String createForm(@ModelAttribute Meal meal) {
    return "meals/form";
}

@PostMapping
public ModelAndView create(@Valid Meal meal,  BindingResult result,
                           RedirectAttributes redirect) {
    Iterable<Student> students = this.studentRepository.findAll();
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("meals/form", "formErrors", result.getAllErrors());
    }
    meal = this.mealRepository.save(meal);
    redirect.addFlashAttribute("globalMessage", "view.success");
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/m/{meal.id}", "meal.id", meal.getId());
}
```

And lastly my view -> form.html

```
<form id="mealForm" th:action="@{/m/(form)}" th:object="${meal}" action="#" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mealName">Meal Name</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{mealName}" th:class="${'form-control' + (#fields.hasErrors('mealName') ? ' is-invalid' : '')}">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mealCook">Meal Cook</label>
        <select th:field="*{mealCook}">
            <option th:each= ??
                    th:value= ??
                    th:text= ??</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now the goal is to add 1 student to a meal by selecting the studentName from a dropdown menu in a form.

But I'm stuggling on how to pass a list of students from the controller to the view and display it in a dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add *student list* in controller wherever open the form:

```
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("studentList");
    model.addObject(students) // get list from database or...
    // students =studentRepository.findAll() or use your exclusive query
```

And `<option>`:

```
<option th:each="item : ${studentList}"
        th:value=${item.id} // value you want...
        th:text=${item.name}>
</option>
```

and change entities:

**Meal.java**:

```
@Entity
    public class Meal {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "meel_cook_id")
  private Student mealCook;

  private String mealName;

  private int mealPrice;
```

**Student.java**:

```
@Entity
 public class Student {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String studentName;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "mealCook")
@JsonBackReference
private Meal meal;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've managed to display the students in the dropdown menu but the student (mealCook) won't display in my list overview. Do you have any idea how I could fix this problem? I've added 2 pictures to make it more clear.

https://ibb.co/m5KLYXx
https://ibb.co/g3fTbSV

Comment: Check the database and make sure the data is stored

Comment: Everything gets stored just fine except the name of the student, it is stored as meal_cook_id : NULL for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the list of students as an attribute to the model in your controller.
e.g.,

```
@GetMapping(params = "form")
public String createForm(@ModelAttribute Meal meal, Model theModel) {
    theModel.addAttribute("students", studentRepository.findAll());

    return "meals/form";
}
```

Then you can read this attribute by using the command.

```
<option th:each="student:${students}"
                    th:value="${student.studentName}"
                    th:text="${student.studentName}">

</option>
```